# How to de-fragment docx files for using with Apache POI 3.8?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, defragmentation

I'm trying to find & replace text passages in docx files with POI 3.8 like described [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/201012.mbox/%3C1291298981596-3289423.post@n5.nabble.com%3E).

That works just fine if I insert my tags on the first run. But as soon as I re-open the docx file and do some modifications, Word actually does fragment across runs of text. So for example, "hello world" might be:

`<w:r><w:t>Hello wo</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00FB0672"><w:t>rld</w:t></w:r>`

Such fragmentation will be due to things like change tracking, formatting, and spell checking I think.

Does anybody have an idea how to ...

a) ... disable this feature in MS Word?

b) ... somehow de-fragment the docx file afterwards?

c) ... any other solution to get rid of this fragmentation?

I already tried to save the file as .doc/.odt and re-save the file to .docx. But these fragmentations still persist...

Any help highly appreciated — thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Word, the features you want to and can turn off are spelling and grammar checking, and rsid insertion.

This is for docx4j (a project I manage), not POI, but [VariablePrepare](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/datastorage/migration/VariablePrepare.java) shows you what needs to be done to de-fragment if you can't prevent it in Word.  Since POI uses a similar XML marshalling/unmarshalling approach (albeit XML Beans, not JAXB), you should be able to convert that code to use the POI API.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I tried your class VariablePrepare and it works. But this consumes 130 MB memory for a "hello-world" word file. Is that normal? Now I get anOutOfMemoryException when called within my application. Is there an option in MS Word 2010 where I can disable rsid insertion? I didn't found it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this case, memory is used by JAXB context init, and XSLT.  You'd need to profile it to find out how much each uses.  But 130 MB doesn't surprise me; can you allocate more (-Xmx etc)?

Comment: Re RSID, see http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/turnoff-rsid-s-spell-check-grammar-check-in-generated-xml-t46.html   IN summary Trust centre > Privacy Options > UNcheck "Store random number to improve combine accuracy"

Comment: thanks alot jason. I used -XX:MaxPermSize=196M to provide more memory since I got a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space.